# Cloud Function is failing to write to the Map data type in Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Webhook that POSTs a JSON to my Cloud Function Trigger URL.

I want the Cloud Function to parse the JSON and write it to my Cloud Firestore.

I've tested the Webhook on webhook.site & requestbin.com : they are both receiving the POST request perfectly.

Additionally, this is not an authenticated request, and I deployed the function through the Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Function Console. I did not deploy this through the CLI, or through an application setup with firebase.

This Function does require HTTPS.

I was able to get my function to write to the Firestore, but it did not write to the fields within a Map - I've included screenshots at the bottom to show what my Firestore looks like within the Firebase / Google Cloud Platform Console.

What syntax do I need to provide to make sure my Cloud Function takes the JSON and writes to the Firestore while respecting the Map data type?

Do I need to declare people_Email = map? and if I do, how would that be accomplished?

**index.js**

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    var billing = ""; // Do I even need to declare every nest of the complex JSON?
        var people_EmailHome = "";
        var people_FirstName = "";
        var people_LastName = "";

    // Write to Firestore - People Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
        people_EmailHome: payload.billing.email,
        people_FirstName: payload.billing.first_name,
        people_LastName: payload.billing.last_name,
    });

    return res.status(200).end();

};
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
      "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2"
  }
}
```

**My Webhook that delivers a POST JSON to my Cloud Function URL:**

```json
{
     "billing": {
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "first_name": "First",
          "last_name": "Last"
     }
}
```

**Screenshots of my Cloud Firestore**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of payload and also of expected structure in Firestore ?

Comment: my payload should be the JSON, I've posted. `{"billing": { "email": "test@test.com", "first_name": "First", "last_name": "Last" } }` and the expected structure is collection("people").doc() Additionally, you should see the screenshots at the bottom, where I show people_Email is map with a string of people_EmailHome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What syntax do I need to provide to make sure my Cloud Function takes
> the JSON and writes to the Firestore while respecting the Map data
> type?

The following will do the trick:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
       people_Email: { people_EmailHome: payload.billing.email },
       people_Names: { people_FirstName: payload.billing.first_name, people_LastName: payload.billing.last_name }
    });

    return res.status(200).end();

};
```

Comment: Do I need to declare the variables like: `var people_EmailHome = "";` to tell the Firestore that this is a string? I was getting undefined payload errors before I started declaring the data types.

Comment: No you don't have to, it is treated as a key of the key/value pair.